# Create barchart using openpyxl, with dates on x axis

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a dataset where I would like to create a barchart (using openpyxl) with dates on the x axis, and cost on the y. The categories will be differentiated by color.

Data
(already in excel)

```
Category 2021-01    2021-02
Network  10         20
Other    20         30
Storage  10         10
Compute  10         10
Total:   50         70
```

[image]

Desired

Something similar to this, with date being on the X axis

[image]

Is this possible, or would I have to change the layout of the data in excel?

Doing

```
path = "C:/Users/th/data.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = BarChart()
c1.title = "Global Costs"
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost in Dollars"
c1.x_axis.title = "Category"
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'mm/dd/yy'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days";
c1 = deepcopy(c1)
c1.style = 39


data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=9, max_col=3, max_row=14)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

cats = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=10, max_row=13)
c1.set_categories(cats)



sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "E9")
wb_obj.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Is this possible, or would I have to change the layout of the data in excel?
Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to adjust your Reference boundaries to include the right data and category ranges and add `from_rows=True` when calling `add_data`, since you're working with a transposed-relative-to-expectations layout of data.

```python
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, ScatterChart, LineChart, StockChart, AreaChart, AreaChart3D

path = "data.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = BarChart()
c1.type = "col"
c1.style = 39
c1.shape = 4
c1.title = "Global Costs"
c1.y_axis.title = "Cost in Dollars"
c1.x_axis.title = "Category"

data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=6)
cats = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, max_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=1)
c1.add_data(data, from_rows=True, titles_from_data=True)
c1.set_categories(cats)

sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "A9")
wb_obj.save("sample.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: Oops - didn't see the x-axis title in your code attempt is a bit inappropriate, since it should probably be "Month", but that's an easy fix.

Comment: Wow thank you! There are no examples of this in the document

Comment: Yeah, I had to grep the source code to find it.

Comment: What does this mean (Grep the source code?)

Comment: I downloaded the source code and did a text search, looking for "add_data" in any of the files.  Eventually I found where the add_data function was declared and saw that it had `from_rows` as a possible parameter.  `openpyxl/chart/_chart.py:    def add_data(self, data, from_rows=False, titles_from_data=False)`

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I was stuck on this!!